# Why A is diagonalizable?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization

This is a part of a question.
Let $A$ be a real $2\times 2$ matrix such that $\,\det A=1,\operatorname{tr}A>2$.
Why is $A$ diagonalizable?

The original question asks to prove that $A$ and $B$ have a common eigenvector if $\det B=1,\operatorname{tr}B>2,\operatorname{tr}\left(ABA^{-1}B^{-1}\right)=2$.

Comment: Just easily check that $A$ has two distinct eigenvalues.

Comment: Why is that so.

Comment: The determinant is the product of the eigenvalues and the trace is the sum. Think about it if you have never heard these statements, they are important.

Comment: I thought those properties hold if the diagonalizability is guarenteed, isn't it?

Comment: @Cauchy That is up to you. It is really immediate from the assumptions.

Comment: a quadratic $ax^2+bx+c$ has two distinct roots if $b^2-4ac>0$. This may help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\lambda_1, \lambda)_2$ are the two (complex) eigenvalues of a real matrix $A$ (size $2\times 2$), then we always have $\det(A) = \lambda_1 \lambda_2$ and $\operatorname{tr} A  = \lambda_1 + \lambda_2$.

If the eigenvalues would be equal the eigenvalues would be $1,1$ or $-1,-1$ and thus give trace $-2$ or $2$ which is not the case.

So, the eigenvalues are different, and we now have a base of eigenvectors: the two linearly independent (because they have different eigenvalues) eigenvectors of $A$ must form a base of $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: Is it okay to assume that A has two eigenvalues? This is a point where I became stuck. A might has no eigenvalue at all.

Comment: Read up about the Jordan normal form.

Comment: That is too far.. I don't know that

Comment: @Luke why? For two different eigenvalues we don't need Jordan?

Comment: @Cauchy the characteristic polynomial of a $2 \times 2$ matrix has degree $2$, and (by the fundamental theorem of algebra) will always have two roots (up to multiplicity).  These roots are the eigenvalues.

Comment: @Cauchy a polynomial of degree 2 has 2 complex roots.

Answer (score 1):

This is because the characteristic polynomial of $A$ is
$$\chi_A(\lambda)=\lambda^2-(\operatorname{Tr} A) \lambda+\det A,$$
and that it has two distinct real roots since its discriminant is
$$\Delta=(\operatorname{Tr} A)^2-4\det A>4-4=0$$
by the hypotheses.

Answer (score 0):

MooS' first & prompt comment brings up the principal reason: $A$ is diagonalisable because the *eigenvalues must be different* under these givens.

$A\text{ certainly has two}\:\mathbb C\text{omplex eigenvalues}$
$$\lambda_1 = x+iy\quad\text{and}\quad\lambda_2 = \frac 1{\lambda_1}
 = {x-iy\over x^2+y^2}$$
owing to the condition $\,\det A=1$, in particular both eigenvalues are non-zero. If the imaginary part $\,y\,$ were to be non-zero, then the condition $\:\operatorname{tr}A>2\:$ could not be satisfied. Hence both eigenvalues are real and even greater than  $0\,$.

The trace-condition can be read as AM-GM inequality 
$$\operatorname{tr}A>2\quad\iff\quad
\frac 12\left(\lambda_1 + \frac1{\lambda_1}\right)\:>\:
\lambda_1\cdot\frac1{\lambda_1} = 1$$
which is strict, and strictness implies
$\lambda_1\ne\frac1{\lambda_1}=\lambda_2\,$.